# How to use Stanford NER in Apache Spark

Tags: nltk, stanford-nlp

We are thinking of using Stanford NER for entity extraction for our domain. So we need to retrain the classifier. However, we have Apache Spark environment. I am wondering can anybody suggest how to use Stanford NER on Spark. I am using python 2.7 + NLTK.

Any response would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The maintainers of Spark have written some code for running Stanford CoreNLP annotations.

The GitHub project is here: https://github.com/databricks/spark-corenlp